# Changing the sda partition number in a clonezilla img

Tags: partition, clonezilla, gparted

I want to copy a linux system from a computer to mine. That linux system is using two partitions. ("/" and an other one)

I used clonezilla to copy thoses two partitions and put them in an image. But when I clonned them, they kept their partitions names wich are sda5 and sda7. When I use Gparted on my computer I already have an sda5 partition so if I use clonezilla it will erease that partition to copy the other one.

Is there any way to avoid that? Maybe renaming the partition inside the img?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you restore with Clonezilla, the partition letters it's showing for the source system are just there so you can remember which partition is which. It won't actually restore sda5 to sda5, for example. However if you are going to restore partitions from a Clonezilla image, you need to first create corresponding partitions on your destiation disk.

For example, on your source computer you cloned /dev/sda5 and /dev/sda7 to an image. On your destination you have 2 existing partitions, say /dev/sda2 and /dev/sda3. You will need to create two more partitions, which may end up being /dev/sda8 and /dev/sda9. Then you will launch clonezilla and select "device to image", and then "restore from parts". You will then select which partitions in the image you want to restore (i.e. /dev/sda5 and /dev/sda7), and then it will ask you where you want to restore them, so you'll select the new partitions you just created (e.g. /dev/sda8 and /dev/sda9). And that should be it!

Comment: Thank you, I am home right now so I can't test it, but I will tomorow and let you know.